# Printing object gives different value than printing a property of that object

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I've got a strange situation in my typescript file where these two `console.info` calls show separate values for `overage`:

```js
this.rows[index].overage = 17;
console.info(this.rows[index].overage);
console.info(this.rows[index]);
```

The first printout shows the expected value of 17.  The second, where the whole object is displayed, show the old value of 90 for overage.  How is that possible?

Rows is defined like so:

```js
rows: UsageDisplayData[];

export interface UsageDisplayData {
    id: number;
    overage: number;
    // A bunch of other properties
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without an MVCE exactly what is happening, but the expanded view in the dev console is usually a "live" view and thus will show whatever the latest value is. Example:

```
let obj = { m: 17 };
console.info(obj.m);
console.info(obj);
obj.m = 90;
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, this is what's happening. You can use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj)))` to log an object's state at a given time.